# How to make <div> responsive width - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a status update `<div>` like the one shown in the picture below with three options:

```
1-Personal -> <div style="width:300px;">
2-Product  -> <div style="width:300px;">
3-Payment  -> <div style="width:270px;">
```

After giving `inline width` they display similarly to the picture below, but when I try to open it in mobile it gets out of window.

I tried using `width:100%` also but this makes the `<div>` very small on the Desktop screen.

How can I resize it with jQuery or Javascript?

[image: Display Image]

Comment: so does width: 100% work for you on mobile but not in a bigger screen? Have you tried media queries to only apply the css changes for specific screen sizes?

Comment: Yes I'm using bootstrap so i have all media queries set

Comment: @SagarSingh, you should put style like `display:block` or `display:inline-block` along with width.

Comment: if the `width: 100%` makes it smaller, it means that its parents are not set to 100% and it just gives it the minimal size it needs. Give its containers also `witdth: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with the viewport meta tag. ie:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score -1):

Set to

```
1-Personal -> <div style="width:33%;">
2-Product  -> <div style="width:33%;">
3-Payment  -> <div style="width:33%;">
```

Comment: if 100% makes div small then how can 33% will make it!